# Profiling xsl performance

Tags: xml, performance, xslt

I have been looking into profiling of xslt and have come across the XSLT profilier in Visual Studio 2010.

The problem I am having is that my xsl is spread across many templates and across hundreds of files. When I run the profiler against an xsl file it is throwing error, saying that templates do not exist or variables/parameters have not been set. These are all found in other xsl files from the project.

Does anyone know how I could get this working with my current situation or recommend any other methods?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about the profiler in VS but you could try the one in Saxon: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xsl/performanceanalysis.xml